# Storm 0.9.0 and log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, apache-storm

I am using slf4j with log4j binding.
Storm 0.9.0 is using slf4j with logback as the binding.

So, I had to exclude logback to avoid multiple bindings.
Is it going to hurt Storm in anyway to have log4j instead of logback?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to run your topology and see.

Comment: I did and it does work and Storm is logging but I guess logback was chosen for performance reasons. So, I am not sure how much performance is affected, for example